# How do you perform linear regression if you have more than 50 variables and are a mix of continuous and categorical variables?

Tags: multiple-regression

I want to perform linear regression and formulate a model but have 50 predictor variables. How should i proceed? Variables are a mix of categorical and continuous variables.

Comment: Assuming you have identified a dependent variable, have you heard of the Lasso as a variable selection technique? It is scale invariant.

Comment: What particular problems are you trying to solve?  Are you thinking this is too many predictors?  Why do you feel that way?  How many data points do you have?  What are you trying to learn?

Answer (score -4):

Scale all continuous to -1+1 and encode all categorical to binary via "one hot encoding". Then use the usual regression model. 
Here is an example of how to do so in Python (sklearn) https://www.kaggle.com/drchrisarthur/liberty-mutual-group-property-inspection-prediction/load-and-scale-function/code

Comment: Why? Please elaborate rather than just stating something without a reference

Comment: @Repmat this is a standard approach and many algorithms explicitly propose that in their documentation. It works for me. The user didn't ask why but rather what.

Comment: I don't agree with the sentiment you propose a method without any argument for why one should implement it. I could counter by saying that linear regression is scale invariant so there is no need to rescale.

Comment: This is very unhelpful without further clarification

Comment: Funny how nobody else have answered this question and none of the critics has put forward specific reasons not to follow my advice :-)